# Each row and column of a matrix $M$ sums to $s \in \mathbb{N}$, prove that $M$ is a square matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

M is a matrix of non-negative integers so that each row and column of a matrix $M$ sums to $s \in \mathbb{N}$.

(a) Prove that $M$ is a square matrix.

(b) Prove that $M$ can be written as the sum of $s$ permutation matrices.

This makes sense to me because if I start with a matrix of all 1's for example, for the row and column sums to be the same of course it must be square. Then if I change the value of element $(i,j)$, I will change the value of one of the $i$'th column and the $j$'th row by some amount. So I will have to add that same amount to every other row and column, without adding it to any of the rows or columns that have already had the value added to them.

I am, however, having trouble formulating this as a proof, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hint for part (a): consider the sum of all elements of the matrix, first summing by row then column, and vice versa.

Comment: For (b), you could use induction on $s$. Show that if $s>0$, then you can always subtract some permutation matrix without making negative entries.